# Switching between views in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    //  UIScreen represents the entire screen. Its bounds method
    //  returns the rectangle that corresponds to the entire screen
    //  CGRect is a C struct that used to group four floating
    //  point values that represent the x and y coordinates of the upper left
    //  corner, as well as the width and the height.
    //

    CGRect windowRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds];
    UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:windowRect];
    [window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

   [self setWindow:window];
    UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
    window.rootViewController = vc;

    self.mainView = vc.view;
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    //Window is now visible
    //Add created views to the mainView to make them visible.

    //Example : add a "Hello World" label
    UIView *dealerView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.mainView.bounds];

    UIView *view1=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.mainView.bounds];
    CGRect labelRect = { 150.0, 150.0, 150.0, 50.0 };
    UIButton *button1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:labelRect];
    [button1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [button1 setTitle:@"ENTER HERE" forState: (UIControlState)UIControlStateNormal];
    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(enterHereClicked:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button1 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    [view1 addSubview:button1];

    [dealerView addSubview:view1];

    return YES;
}

-(void) enterHereClicked:(UIButton *) button{

   CGRect labelRect = { 150.0, 400.0, 150.0, 50.0 };

    UIButton *sender=button;
    UIView *view1=[sender superview];
    UIView *view2=[[sender superview]superview];
   [view1 removeFromSuperview];

    UIView *view=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.mainView.bounds];

    UIButton *button2 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:labelRect];
    [button2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [button2 setTitle:@"Another View" forState: (UIControlState)UIControlStateNormal];
    [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(clickView:) forControlEvents:
     UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [view addSubview:button2];
    [view2 addSubview: view];

}
-(void)clickView:(UIButton *) button{

    NSLog(@"anand");
    UIButton *sender=button;
    UIView *view1=[sender superview];
      UIView *view3=[[sender superview]superview];
    [view1 removeFromSuperview];
     CGRect labelRect = { 150.0, 400.0, 150.0, 50.0 };
    UIView *view=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:labelRect];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

    [view3 addSubview:view];



}



I have edited the code as per you advise. But still not working.
```

I am creating a new view dealerview and adding and removing the subviews views from it. I am going somewhere wrong but still could not figure it out.
   Looks like I am going wrong in the -(BOOL) application method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIButton *addVehicleBackbtn=button;
UIView *addVehicleView=[addVehicleBackbtn superview];
[addVehicleView setHidden:YES];
```

I did hide the View using setHidden:YES  in order to switch back between the views.

Answer (score 1):

It's very atypical to do this sort of thing in the app delegate. It would be better to do this in a subclass of `UIViewController` and add an instance of that subclass as the `rootViewController` of the `UINavigationController` you make key and visible in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

You also likely do not want to remove the root view of a `UIViewController` from it's super view. Currently, you care creating an action for a button that removes its superview, `vc.view`, from the view hierarchy. The problem is `view1` and `self.mainView` are the same so with:

```
UIView *view1=[sender superview];
[view1 removeFromSuperview];
[self.mainView addSubview:view];
```

You're removing a view from the view hierarchy then adding a view to the view that's just been removed and expecting to see it.

You should have one view that acts as a container for `button1` and another view that acts as a container for `button2` but are both added and removed to/from `self.mainView`.

Comment: My assignment should not use any controllers. I should switch only views in this assignment.

Comment: @Harish If you are fighting this hard against the standard patterns of the system, it is a pretty good indication that you are doing it wrong or... at least... in a totally non-standard fashion that is likely to break in the future.

Comment: @Harish I would probably be easier to manipulate your view hierarchy if you held a reference to the views you're working with. Create a property for `dealerView` and for `UIView *view1=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.mainView.bounds];`. That way you can avoid things like `UIView *view2=[[sender superview]superview];` You add subviews to `dealerView` but you never add it to the view hierarchy. For example `[self.mainView addSubview: dealerView];`